# Several routes in one component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

Suppose there is a component - `UsersComponent`, and it has two methods: `getAlUsers()` and `getUser(id)`. In the `@RouteConfig` we can use only one name of the component (constructor will be called default ), but we can not specify what kind of a class method must be called. Is it possible to define something like this:

```
{
    path: '/users/',
    component: UsersComponent,
    name: 'Users'
},
{
    path: '/users/getAllUsers',
    component: UsersComponent.getAllUsers,
    name: 'GetAllUsers'
},
{
    path: '/users/getUser',
    component: UsersComponent.getUser,
    name: 'GetUsers'
}
```

Or is it impossible to make means Angular 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common use case for component nesting and using sub components for the different actions like "user list" and "user details". The idea is to use pretty fine grained components with a very focused use case. If you have common code (e.g. loading data via http), consider moving this logic into a service that is used by all components.

You can achieve this by referencing a "UserComponent" in your top level Component routing with the "..." notation. Then inside this "UserComponent" define another routing with two configs for `/` and `/:id` such that you reference two child components "user list" and "user details".

Parent Route Config:

```
  {
    path: '/users/...',
    name: 'Users',
    component: UserComponent
  }
```

Route Config in the UserComponent:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: "/", name: "User List", component: UserListComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: "/:id", name: "User Detail", component: UserDetailComponent },
])
```

Comment: Thank's, it's work) You may suggest how can write all the routes in a separate file in order not to write them inside the components?

Comment: Of course, technically you could do some "god" module and export all the route configs, but therefore you would also have to import all components in there. This should not be done! The idea is to split the whole app into parts and to build from those components. With the setup above, you could easily move the whole User stuff under a different url by just changing the path in the parent, which is really great for maintainability and reuse.